# How to enable C++17 standard in VSCode C++ Extension

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, c++17

I want to switch the c++11 to c++17 in vs code. I tried following instructions, but it didn't work.

tasks.json

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-Wall",
            "-std=c++17",
            "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    }
]
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            
      "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

launch.json

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [
            
        ],
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
    }
]
```

settings.json

```
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
"files.associations": {
    "*html": "html",
    "iostream": "cpp",
    "iosfwd": "cpp",
    "ostream": "cpp",
    "istream": "cpp",
    "fstream": "cpp",
    "new": "cpp",
    "__bit_reference": "cpp",
    "__config": "cpp",
    "__debug": "cpp",
    "__errc": "cpp",
    "__functional_base": "cpp",
    "__hash_table": "cpp",
    "__locale": "cpp",
    "__mutex_base": "cpp",
    "__node_handle": "cpp",
    "__nullptr": "cpp",
    "__split_buffer": "cpp",
    "__string": "cpp",
    "__threading_support": "cpp",
    "__tree": "cpp",
    "__tuple": "cpp",
    "algorithm": "cpp",
    "array": "cpp",
    "atomic": "cpp",
    "bit": "cpp",
    "bitset": "cpp",
    "cctype": "cpp",
    "chrono": "cpp",
    "cmath": "cpp",
    "complex": "cpp",
    "cstdarg": "cpp",
    "cstddef": "cpp",
    "cstdint": "cpp",
    "cstdio": "cpp",
    "cstdlib": "cpp",
    "cstring": "cpp",
    "ctime": "cpp",
    "cwchar": "cpp",
    "cwctype": "cpp",
    "deque": "cpp",
    "exception": "cpp",
    "functional": "cpp",
    "initializer_list": "cpp",
    "iomanip": "cpp",
    "ios": "cpp",
    "iterator": "cpp",
    "limits": "cpp",
    "list": "cpp",
    "locale": "cpp",
    "map": "cpp",
    "memory": "cpp",
    "mutex": "cpp",
    "numeric": "cpp",
    "optional": "cpp",
    "queue": "cpp",
    "ratio": "cpp",
    "set": "cpp",
    "sstream": "cpp",
    "stack": "cpp",
    "stdexcept": "cpp",
    "streambuf": "cpp",
    "string": "cpp",
    "string_view": "cpp",
    "system_error": "cpp",
    "tuple": "cpp",
    "type_traits": "cpp",
    "typeinfo": "cpp",
    "unordered_map": "cpp",
    "utility": "cpp",
    "vector": "cpp",
    "thread": "cpp"
}
```

Also changed to c++17 in the C/C++ Configurations (UI).

I'm having trouble compiling my work due to this issue.
Having this warning generated:

> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <
> Starting build...
> /usr/bin/g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 /Users/aziznosirov/Documents/cpp_udemy/btp305_w2_p1/*.cpp -o /Users/aziznosirov/Documents/cpp_udemy/btp305_w2_p1/w2_p1
> /Users/aziznosirov/Documents/cpp_udemy/btp305_w2_p1/w2_p1.cpp:43:14: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
> t.addEvent("  0-arg Constructor");

You can see although it says c++17 on the compiler when building, it still generates a warning mentioning c++11.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `Build Task` we can see that the code is actually being compiled explicitly with the `-std=c++17` flag.

I suspect that the compiler that is being used is not a recent one , `GCC -7` had experimental support for C++ 17 features which could be used by using
`-std=c++1z` flag.

Starting GCC 8 , the Compiler had full C++17 support .

I suggest updating the GCC package.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just needed to add a const. My c++17 was actually working.